# SQL Server 2005 login issue

Tags: sql-server-2005, login

I have SQL Server 2005 SP3 running one server with mixed mode authentication. I tried to connect to the database engine, using the SQL Management Studio installed on the same machine. But I get a login error that says

```
Login failed for user *user*, (Microsoft SQL Sever, Error: 18456)
```

Strangely I'm able to connect to the Database through SQL Server Management Studio running on a different server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem myself. Thank you all for your answers. I found this link which solved the problem
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ff81398a-c959-4d87-89b1-57f6aa843bab/

Basically, I started Reporting Services configuration by going to **Start > Program > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools** and connected to **Reporting Server**. Then filled out the information in **Database setup node** and clicked apply. After this I was able to use SQL Server Management Studio in the local machine to connect to the SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the logs?

Although the error message on screen is not very helpful there may be more helpful information in the log itself, in particular the State value.

Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx) to see if this makes it any clearer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: LOL - Is there an echo in here...?

Answer (score 0):

From Google:

[Error 18456](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx) an article describing how you can look at the stat information in the server log for the corresponding error to get some mor information about the cause of the error message.